# PHP Adding a method to a class via the constructor

Tags: php, class, oop, callback

how would I go about adding a method to a PHP class via its constructor to be called back at a later date?

Say I have a PHP class like this:

```
class Action
{
    public $callback = null;

    public function __construct(callable $callback)
    {
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to call that method like this:

```
$action = new Action(function($value) {
    // do something with $value;
});

$action->callback('abc');
```

However when I do the above I get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Action::callback()
```

I've tried googling for some answers however so far I haven't had much luck, any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: use [__call](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) - https://3v4l.org/oBR0L

Comment: @LawrenceCherone do you have an example of how I can use __call()?

Comment: visit the 3v4l link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a **function** named 'callback'. You can get the property to call it:

```php
call_user_func($action->callback, 'abc');
```

or

```php
$fn = $action->callback;
$fn('abc');
```

Example:

```php
class Action
{
    public $callback = null;

    public function __construct(callable $callback)
    {
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }
}
$action = new Action(function($value) {
    var_dump($value);
});

call_user_func($action->callback,12); // int(12)

$fn = $action->callback;
$fn('abc'); // string(3) "abc"
```